# How can I write this Oracle query (last time per date where time < given time)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for the correct way to write a query for an Oracle DB.

It should select for each unique date (of dateCol column) the last line such that the time part of dateCol2 is lower than '17:30'

```
select * from table where dateCol between to_date('2013-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS') and to_date('2013-02-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS') 
and id='myID' 
and [MISSING PART = the last line such that timepart(dateCol2)<'17:30']
```

I am very new to Oracle/SQL so my question might be missing a lot of things, I'll add whatever I can on any request.

EDIT : so far I understood this:

```
  select * from (select table.*, row_number() over (order by dateCol2 desc) last_row from table
  where dateCol between to_date('2013-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS') 
                    and to_date('2013-02-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS') 
                    and id='myID' 
                    and to_char(dateCol2, 'hh24:mi') < '17:30')
  where last_row = 1
  group by dateCol
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are only storing the date in `datecol` (ie when you insert you TRUNC the date) then the between is not required. If you are storing a non zero time in there too, then the between also needs tweaking.

To check the time, just convert the date to a number in the form `hh24mi` (which results in a number between 0 and 2359) and check for that less than 1730

if `datecol` has a non 00:00:00 time element for the dates:

```
select distinct dateCol 
  from table 
 where dateCol >= to_date('2013-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
   and dateCol < to_date('2013-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + 1
   and id='myID' 
   and to_number(to_char(dateCol2, 'hh24mi')) < 1730;
```

if `datecol` always has the date with 00:00:00 as the time then :

```
select distinct dateCol 
  from table 
 where dateCol = to_date('2013-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
   and id='myID' 
   and to_number(to_char(dateCol2, 'hh24mi')) < 1730;
```

edit from clarification

```
select *
  from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by datecol 
                                       order by dateCol2) first_row,
               row_number() over (partition by datecol 
                                  order by dateCol2 desc) last_row
          from table t
         where dateCol = to_date('2013-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
           and id='myID' 
           and to_number(to_char(dateCol2, 'hh24mi')) < 1730)
 where first_row = 1
    or last_row = 1;
```

Comment: @statquant ok if `datecol` is always 00:00:00 then the 2nd variant is what you want. Last statement? the `and to_number(to_char(dateCol2, 'hh24mi')) < 1730` part gets all records that are less than 17:30. thats what you wanted?

Comment: almost I want the LAST (and also the FIRST but I guess It is just a different function) of the records that are less than 17:30

Comment: @statquant i see. see the last SQL edit with `row_number()` that will fetch only the first (min) and last (max) row where datecol2 is less than 1730. eg  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d201d/2

Comment: @DazzaL - don't you need to partition those by `datecol`?

Comment: @AlexPoole as the posters query was a fixed individual date, then not in this specific case, though perhaps in case they tweak it, it's probably more clear to have it there

Comment: @DazzaL - I think that was a mistake fixed in an earlier edit to the question; it's a month range now, and the title has 'last time per date'. Completely understand the confusion though... *8-)

Comment: Yes I edited it now, thanks, but as far as parenthesis are concerned is it ok to group at the end of the statement ?

Comment: @statquant yes the group by at the end is ok though you can only select the `datecol` and not `*` or you'll get an error (and you have an excess right parenthesis at the end of your final SQL

Answer (score 1):

if you want to select for each date (dateCol) the whole row for most recent dateCol2, before 17:30, I would go for something like

```
   select * 
     from table
    where (dateCol, dateCol2)  in (
        select dateCol, max(dateCol2) 
          from table 
         where dateCol between to_date('2013-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
                           and to_date('2013-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
           and id='myID' 
           and to_char(dateCol2, 'hh24:mi') < '17:30'
         group by dateCol
    )
```

Not sure about your between condition with the same date, but I think you just entered twice the same date.

Edit:

```
       select * 
         from table t
  innner join (
            select dateCol, 
                   min(dateCol2) first, 
                   max(dateCol2) last
              from table 
             where trunc(dateCol) = to_date('2013-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
               and id='myID' 
               and to_char(dateCol2, 'hh24:mi') < '17:30'
             group by dateCol
              ) 
              sub s
           on t.dateCol  = s.dateCol
          and (t.dateCol2 = s.first
            or t.dateCol2 = s.last)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like this ,even though it is not very smart... dateCol

```
select * from table 
where dateCol between to_date('2013-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
                  and to_date('2013-01-01','YYYY-MMDD') 
and id='myID' and dateCol<trunc(dateCol)+17.5/24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select trunc(t.dateCol),
       max(t.your_column) keep (dense_rank last order by t.dateCol)
    from table t 
    where t.dateCol between to_date('2013-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2013-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
      and t.id='myID' 
      and t.dateCol
```

Comment: Unfortunately I just can't insert main thing in this code. You must end this code with: group by trunc(t.dateCol)